# Tricky SQL Server Pivot Table for Survey

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a SQL Server view with following data:

```
ID   clientID  surveyID    questionID     q_optionID   q_ans_text
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1       1          1           1            NULL            Yes
2       1          1           2             18             NULL 
3       1          1           3             19             NULL
4       2          1           1            NULL             No
5       2          1           2             18             NULL
6       2          1           3             19             NULL
7       3          2           1            NULL            Yes 
8       3          2           2             15             NULL 
9       3          2           3             13             NULL
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
ClientID  SurveyID   Q1    Q2    Q3  
------------------------------------
   1          1     Yes    18    19   
   2          1      No    18    19   
   3          2     Yes    15    13
```

Where the conditional `NULL` values are ignored and the proper answer is placed in the column. I have looked at Pivot table examples, but they seem to be focusing on single column pivots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to perform this transformation you will need to `UNPIVOT` and then `PIVOT` the data. The `UNPIVOT` will take the values from your `q_optionID` and  `q_ans_text` columns and transform it into two columns one with the value and the column name.

There are two ways that you can `PIVOT` this, you can hard-code all of the values using a static version or you can use dynamic sql.  In order to `UNPIVOT` the data you need to be sure that the data is of the same datatype, so converting might be necessary.

**Static PIVOT:**

```
select clientid, surveyid, 
    questionid,
    value,
    col
  from
  (
    select clientid, surveyid, questionid,
      cast(q_optionID as varchar(4)) q_optionID,
      q_ans_text
    from yourtable
  ) s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (q_optionID, q_ans_text)
  ) un
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c042f/4)

Unpivot result:

```
| CLIENTID | SURVEYID | QUESTIONID | VALUE |        COL |
---------------------------------------------------------
|        1 |        1 |          1 |   Yes | q_ans_text |
|        1 |        1 |          2 |    18 | q_optionID |
|        1 |        1 |          3 |    19 | q_optionID |
|        2 |        1 |          1 |    No | q_ans_text |
|        2 |        1 |          2 |    18 | q_optionID |
|        2 |        1 |          3 |    19 | q_optionID |
|        3 |        2 |          1 |   Yes | q_ans_text |
|        3 |        2 |          2 |    15 | q_optionID |
|        3 |        2 |          3 |    13 | q_optionID |
```

Then you will apply the `PIVOT` to the result to get your final product.

```
select *
from
(
  select clientid, surveyid, 
    'Q'+cast(questionid as varchar(10)) question,
    value
  from
  (
    select clientid, surveyid, questionid,
      cast(q_optionID as varchar(4)) q_optionID,
      q_ans_text
    from yourtable
  ) s
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (q_optionID, q_ans_text)
  ) un
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for question in (Q1, Q2, Q3)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c042f/5)

**Dynamic PIVOT:**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Q'+cast(questionid as varchar(10))) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT clientid, surveyid,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select clientid, surveyid, 
                  ''Q''+cast(questionid as varchar(10)) question,
                  value
                from
                (
                  select clientid, surveyid, questionid,
                    cast(q_optionID as varchar(4)) q_optionID,
                    q_ans_text
                  from yourtable
                ) s
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for col in (q_optionID, q_ans_text)
                ) un
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for question in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c042f/6)

**UNION ALL/Aggregate with Case Version:**

Now, if you are working in a system that does not have `PIVOT` then you can use a `UNION ALL` to `UNPIVOT` and an aggregate function with a `CASE` to `PIVOT`:

```
select clientid, surveyid,
  max(case when questionid = 1 then value end) Q1,
  max(case when questionid = 2 then value end) Q2,
  max(case when questionid = 3 then value end) Q3
from
(
  select clientid, surveyid, questionid, cast(q_optionID as varchar(10)) value, 'q_optionID' col
  from yourtable
  union all
  select clientid, surveyid, questionid, q_ans_text value, 'q_ans_text' col
  from yourtable
) unpiv
group by clientid, surveyid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c042f/7)

All three will produce the same result:

```
| CLIENTID | SURVEYID |  Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
---------------------------------------
|        1 |        1 | Yes | 18 | 19 |
|        2 |        1 |  No | 18 | 19 |
|        3 |        2 | Yes | 15 | 13 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply...though the data types are mismatched. I tried a cast or convert on the q_optionID and it's not really working.

Comment: @TehFoobar please see my edit to `UNPIVOT` the data the datatypes must be the same

Comment: The type of column "question_OptionID" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: @TehFoobar did you see my changes and this demo? -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c042f/5

Answer (score 1):

Example without an explicit unpivot. Still a very useful technique to know, though!

```
Select
  clientID, 
  SurveyID, 
  [1] as Q1, 
  [2] as Q2,
  [3] as Q3
From (
  Select
    clientID,
    surveyID,
    questionID,
    IsNull(Cast(q_optionID as varchar(10)), q_ans_text) answer
  From
    Answers
) a
Pivot (
  Max(answer)
  For questionID In ([1], [2], [3])
) p
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8552a/8

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  clientid, surveyid,
  max(case when questionid = 1 then coalesce(q_ans_text, cast(q_optionID as char)) else null end) as Q1,
  max(case when questionid = 2 then coalesce(q_ans_text, cast(q_optionID as char)) else null end) as Q2,
  max(case when questionid = 3 then coalesce(q_ans_text, cast(q_optionID as char)) else null end) as Q3
 from yourtable
 group by clientid, surveyid
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9163ba/11